# Recursive function to check all possible paths (from raw material to product)

Tags: r, recursion

I am struggling with a recursive function, who's goal is to determine which raw materials belong to which product. I clouldn't figure out, how to handle multiple possible paths in data frame "db". The wanted function should give: A-B-C-E, A-B-C-F, A-B-D-F for db. My function works for "da". I added it to show what I am after, and it is a bit like bill of materials explosion, but not exactly.

```
da <- data.frame(parent = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D"),
                 child = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
db <- data.frame(parent = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "C"),
                 child = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_path <- function(a, df) {
  b <- df$parent[df$child == a]
  if (length(b) == 0) {
    return(a)
  } else {
    return(c(my_path(b, df), a))
  }
}
end_points <- da$child[is.na(match(da$child, da$parent))]
lapply(end_points, function(x) my_path(x, da)) # -> ok
end_points <- db$child[is.na(match(db$child, db$parent))]
lapply(end_points, function(x) my_path(x, db)) # -> not ok
```

Thx & kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for igraph:

```
#the data
db <- data.frame(parent = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "C"),
                 child = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#create a graph
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(db)

#plot the graph
plot(g)
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
#find all vertices that have no ingoing resp. outgoing edges
starts <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0] 
finals <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "out") == 0]

#find paths, you need to loop if starts is longer than 1
res <- all_simple_paths(g, from = starts[[1]], to = finals)
#[[1]]
#+ 4/6 vertices, named, from 4b85bd1:
#[1] A B C E
#
#[[2]]
#+ 4/6 vertices, named, from 4b85bd1:
#[1] A B C F
#
#[[3]]
#+ 4/6 vertices, named, from 4b85bd1:
#[1] A B D F

#coerce to vectors
lapply(res, as_ids)
```

Comment: This helps a lot, but if I didn't know that "A" is the starting point, is it possible to avoid the starting point parameter in all_simple_paths? (Simply deleting from does not work).

Comment: Have you read the second comment above where I define `finals`?

Comment: Thanks. Found it. `startings <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0]; all_simple_paths(g, from = startings[1], to = finals)`.